# How to create the password input

Tags: html

How can I make a password input with characters like `*****`?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="password" ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is standard HTML, nothing to do with PHP:

```
<input type="password" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are producing your user interface.

If it is using HTML, then PHP is irrelevant, just use [a password type input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1).