# How to change string text to dots like a password field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a project for my cs class, and I'm trying to change the user input of my textbox to dots, like when typing a password, which is exactly what my textbox is. I'm wondering if there's a way to code this so that it changes each character inputted into dots.

Nothing I tried is working.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  If it's a password field in an HTML form, why do you need to do this manually instead of just using an `input type="password"`?

Comment: We're going to need to see some code for context here.

Comment: What *have* you tried? Have you tried using `type="password"`?

Comment: I think it is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093207/how-to-create-the-password-input

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to simulate the way a password field works on mobile devices? That is to say, the character typed shows as a character for a short period of time, and then it becomes • ?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use css class for this:

```
    #yourInput{
     text-security: disc;
     -webkit-text-security: disc;
     -moz-text-security: disc;
   }
```